# Improving the speed of Yahoo finance (yf) in finding ticker.info values

Tags: python, flask, yahoo-finance

I'm building a website using Flask and I have a function that will access the ticker.info to retrieve "shortName", "currentPrice" and "symbol"

The function is:

```
def lookup1(symbol):
  response = yf.Ticker(symbol)
  df=pd.DataFrame([response.info])
  return df
```

The function works fine, but the issue is that it is very slow, and it seems it queries more info which might be slowing it down, my output in the console shows:

```
INFO: [13/Oct/2021 15:16:06] "GET /login HTTP/1.0" 200 -
INFO: [13/Oct/2021 15:16:06] "GET /static/styles.css HTTP/1.0" 200 -
INFO: [13/Oct/2021 15:16:06] "GET /static/favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 200 -
INFO: [13/Oct/2021 15:16:08] "POST /login HTTP/1.0" 302 -
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): finance.yahoo.com:443
DEBUG: https://finance.yahoo.com:443 "GET /quote/A HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): finance.yahoo.com:443
DEBUG: https://finance.yahoo.com:443 "GET /quote/A/holders HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): finance.yahoo.com:443
DEBUG: https://finance.yahoo.com:443 "GET /quote/A/financials HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): finance.yahoo.com:443
DEBUG: https://finance.yahoo.com:443 "GET /quote/AAPL HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): finance.yahoo.com:443
DEBUG: https://finance.yahoo.com:443 "GET /quote/AAPL/holders HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): finance.yahoo.com:443
DEBUG: https://finance.yahoo.com:443 "GET /quote/AAPL/financials HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): finance.yahoo.com:443
DEBUG: https://finance.yahoo.com:443 "GET /quote/FB HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): finance.yahoo.com:443
DEBUG: https://finance.yahoo.com:443 "GET /quote/FB/holders HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): finance.yahoo.com:443
DEBUG: https://finance.yahoo.com:443 "GET /quote/FB/financials HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): finance.yahoo.com:443
DEBUG: https://finance.yahoo.com:443 "GET /quote/GOOG HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): finance.yahoo.com:443
DEBUG: https://finance.yahoo.com:443 "GET /quote/GOOG/holders HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): finance.yahoo.com:443
DEBUG: https://finance.yahoo.com:443 "GET /quote/GOOG/financials HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): finance.yahoo.com:443
DEBUG: https://finance.yahoo.com:443 "GET /quote/MSFT HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): finance.yahoo.com:443
DEBUG: https://finance.yahoo.com:443 "GET /quote/MSFT/holders HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): finance.yahoo.com:443
DEBUG: https://finance.yahoo.com:443 "GET /quote/MSFT/financials HTTP/1.1" 200 None
INFO: [13/Oct/2021 15:16:19] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 -
INFO: [13/Oct/2021 15:16:19] "GET /static/styles.css HTTP/1.0" 200 -
INFO: [13/Oct/2021 15:16:20] "GET /static/favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 200 -
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): finance.yahoo.com:443
DEBUG: https://finance.yahoo.com:443 "GET /quote/A HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): finance.yahoo.com:443
DEBUG: https://finance.yahoo.com:443 "GET /quote/A/holders HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): finance.yahoo.com:443
DEBUG: https://finance.yahoo.com:443 "GET /quote/A/financials HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): finance.yahoo.com:443
DEBUG: https://finance.yahoo.com:443 "GET /quote/AAPL HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): finance.yahoo.com:443
DEBUG: https://finance.yahoo.com:443 "GET /quote/AAPL/holders HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): finance.yahoo.com:443
DEBUG: https://finance.yahoo.com:443 "GET /quote/AAPL/financials HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): finance.yahoo.com:443
DEBUG: https://finance.yahoo.com:443 "GET /quote/FB HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): finance.yahoo.com:443
DEBUG: https://finance.yahoo.com:443 "GET /quote/FB/holders HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): finance.yahoo.com:443
DEBUG: https://finance.yahoo.com:443 "GET /quote/FB/financials HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): finance.yahoo.com:443
DEBUG: https://finance.yahoo.com:443 "GET /quote/GOOG HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): finance.yahoo.com:443
DEBUG: https://finance.yahoo.com:443 "GET /quote/GOOG/holders HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): finance.yahoo.com:443
DEBUG: https://finance.yahoo.com:443 "GET /quote/GOOG/financials HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): finance.yahoo.com:443
DEBUG: https://finance.yahoo.com:443 "GET /quote/MSFT HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): finance.yahoo.com:443
DEBUG: https://finance.yahoo.com:443 "GET /quote/MSFT/holders HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): finance.yahoo.com:443
DEBUG: https://finance.yahoo.com:443 "GET /quote/MSFT/financials HTTP/1.1" 200 None
INFO:[13/Oct/2021 15:16:32] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 -
INFO:[13/Oct/2021 15:16:32] "GET /static/styles.css HTTP/1.0" 200 -
INFO:[13/Oct/2021 15:16:32] "GET /static/favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 200 -
INFO:[13/Oct/2021 15:16:32] "GET /static/favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 200 -
```

Not sure why there are 2 GET responses? Is there a faster way to do this?
Also not sure why for example stock A is called 3 times?

```
DEBUG: https://finance.yahoo.com:443 "GET /quote/A HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): finance.yahoo.com:443
DEBUG: https://finance.yahoo.com:443 "GET /quote/A/holders HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): finance.yahoo.com:443
DEBUG: https://finance.yahoo.com:443 "GET /quote/A/financials HTTP/1.1" 200 None
```

My funcation in app.py that calles lookup1 in this case is as follows:

```
@app.route("/")
@login_required
def index():
    """Show portfolio of stocks"""
    #querying for the symbol and the corresponding sum of the same stock and the average price paid for the stock
    stocks = db.execute("SELECT symbol, SUM(number_of_shares) as sumshares, AVG(price) as avgprice FROM 'transaction' WHERE user_id = :i_d GROUP BY symbol", i_d=session["user_id"])
    #querying the cash at hand for the user in session
    cash = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = ?", session["user_id"])[0]["cash"]
    totalPortValue = 0

    for stock in stocks:
        df=lookup1(stock['symbol'])
        name = df.iloc[0]['shortName']
        price = float(df.iloc[0]['currentPrice'])
        stock['name'] = name
        if stock['sumshares'] == 0:
            stock['ap'] = 0
            db.execute("DELETE FROM 'transaction' WHERE symbol = :symbol AND user_id =:ui", symbol=df.iloc[0]['symbol'], ui=session["user_id"])
        else:
            stock['ap'] = (stock['sumshares'] * price)/stock['sumshares']
            stock['total'] = stock['sumshares'] * price
            totalPortValue += stock['sumshares'] * price


    availableCash = cash
    grandTotal = availableCash + totalPortValue

    return render_template("/index.html",availableCash=availableCash, stocks=stocks, totalPortValue=totalPortValue, grandTotal=grandTotal)
```

Comment: I'd be careful using `yahoo-finance`. They can turn it off at any time so you should not rely on this package if you intend to commercialize whatever you're building here.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, it's basically for an end of course project. afaik there was an original API from Yahoo, and now a similar code was published here https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance see also https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/

Answer (score 0):

I don't have yet an answer to the above, but the new update to yfinance have a new feature - stats() which enable to speed up the process.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).